# PHP Capitalize str_replace if after dot

Tags: php, str-replace

I've got an str_replace that replaces [++] with the word He, but if the [++] has a dot and space before it or just a dot then it should be a He with capital H otherwise it should be a he with lowercase h.

```
$filterString = "[++] has performed well. [++] is showing good understanding";

echo str_replace("[++]", "Name", $filterString);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your input and output?

Comment: edit your regex to match your spec. probably something like \.[++] => He, then [++] => he

Comment: Do it twice one with "[++]" and one ".[++]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
$filterString = "[++] has performed well. [++] is showing good understanding";

echo str_replace(array(". [++]",".[++]","[++]"), array(". He",".He","he"), $filterString);
```

We can use arrays within str_replace. Simply checking for `. [++]`, `.[++]` first and replacing with `He`, then we check for the remainders and change these to `he`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to make replacing in two steps

```
$filterString = str_replace("\. [++]", ". He", $filterString);
echo str_replace("[++]", "he", $filterString);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can actually use 1 `str_replace()`:

```
$filterString = "[++] has performed well. [++] is showing good understanding";
echo str_replace(array('. [++]', '[++]'), array('. He', 'he'), $filterString);
```

which outputs:

> he has performed well. He is showing good understanding

---

Side Note: Another function [ucfirst()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) provides interesting function that you may want to use: It makes the first character of string to be upper case. If you want every sentence's first character to be upper case, you can explode your input paragraph with delimited `.` and use this function, then `implode()` it back with glue `.`.